# Cakephp - Display list element inside if

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm currently displaying a list using cakephp, but I've been unable to redirect on clicking in an specific elemnt component which has to disappear in some cases, this is what I have:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->Url->build(["controller" => "pages","action" => "index"]);?>">Top 20</a>
<?php  
$a = true;
  if($a){ 
    $prod_pm= '<li><a href="<?= $this->Url->build(["controller" => "Catalogo","action" => "cat",11229])? 
    >">Promotions</a>'; 
  }else{
    $prod_pm = '';
}?>  
<?= $prod_pm ?> 
<li><a href="<?= $this->Url->build(["controller" => "Catalogo","action" => "cat",11050]) ?>"></a>
```

It seems that the php redirected after the href citation is not working that way, also I tried declaring a variable with the code outside and inserting in place of `$this->Url->build(["controller" => "Catalogo","action" => "cat",11229])`
but didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are just inserting a string to the `href` attribute.

Try:

```
$prod_pm = '<li><a href="'.$this->Url->build(["controller" => "Catalogo","action" => "cat",11229]).'">Promotions</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call PHP code from inside a string constant. The `<?=` is just taken as part of the string. Is there any reason why you need the `$prod_pm` variable? Seems like you are making this harder on yourself than it needs to be:

```
<li>...
<?php  
$a = true;
if ($a):
?>
<li><a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Catalogo', 'action' => 'cat', 11229]) ?>">Promotions</a>
<?php
endif;
?>
<li>...
```

or, equivalently,

```
<li>...
<?php  
$a = true;
if ($a) {
    echo $this->Html->tag('li',
        $this->Html->link('Promotions', ['controller' => 'Catalogo', 'action' => 'cat', 11229])
    );
}
?>
<li>...
```